# What does the `relevanceLanguage` parameter really do?

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-data-api

[The YouTube Data API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters) mentions a `relevanceLanguage` parameter, which is defined as follows (emphasis mine).

> The `relevanceLanguage` parameter instructs the API to return search
>   results that are most relevant to the specified language. The
>   parameter value is typically an ISO 639-1 two-letter language code.
>   [...] **Please note that results in other
>   languages will still be returned if they are highly relevant to the
>   search query term.**

I understand the part in bold, but I had a very hard time having the API take my relevant language into consideration. In most requests, the relevant language is completely ignored (examples below).

```
Query           | Relevant Language | Results language
----------------|-------------------|-----------------
Donald Trump    | None              | `en`
                | `fr`              | `en`
                | `de`              | `en`
----------------|-------------------|-----------------
Nicolas Sarkozy | None              | `fr`
                | `en`              | `fr`
                | `de`              | `fr`
```

Hence my question: *what does this parameter actually do?* Ideally, I would like to completely filter out the results that are not in my relevant language, but AFAIK, that's not possible, the alternative being this `relevanceLanguage` parameter.

Comment: I've had the same results. Google APIs in general seem to err on the side of ambiguity.