# Is using the Youtube Data API to specify language-results feasible?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

[Here's an example question from a prior user.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55455028/what-does-the-relevancelanguage-parameter-really-do)

**An additional example**:
if I search *Henrik Lundquist* (Swedish Hockey Player), I will receive primarily English results regardless of therelevancelanguage-parameter, and same goes for *Jimmie Åkesson* (Swedish Politician). Regardless of setting it will still be majority Swedish results.

I'm trying to find a way to find a true solution to filter Youtube queries by language, youtube now has rolled-out automatic translations for many languages and the tool will be much more useful with an option to specify search results.

**My Idea**

I was considering combining the Youtube Data API with [a program such as franc](https://github.com/wooorm/franc) to filter the results by language. It is also beneficial for say, Spanish users to find YouTube videos in Spanish about hockey, rather than being flooded by English videos.

It could just be a simple HTML Page showing the Video title and creator, along with a link to the video.

But does anyone know if combining these to APIs a practical beginner project for exploring youtube-api?

Thank you.

I found a similar website which uses a similar approach, but you are able to find a specific word in the CC for a particular language, https://filmot.com/. I'm not sure how they determine what language the video is (or region).

I will try to contact the creator as well.